# C++ int wrapper class with different values for comparison not working

Tags: c++

Why do the following usage give me an error: Undefined referrence to "Environment::self"
So below is my test case and the class is just below it, header and cpp:
Test:

```
Environment bla;
bla=Environment::CTE;
if(bla==1){
    printf("CTE!");
}else if(bla==Environment::PPE){
    printf("NO: its ppe");
}
```

Header:

```
class Environment{
public:
enum{CTE, PTE, PPE, LOCALHOST};
static int self;
bool operator==(const int& rhs)const;
Environment& operator=(const int &rhs);
};
```

And CPP:

```
#include "Environment.h"

bool Environment::operator==(const int& rhs)const{
if (this->self ==rhs)
    return true;
return false;
}

Environment& Environment::operator=(const int &rhs) {
  if (this->self != rhs) {
  this->self=rhs;
}

  return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared `self` as `static`. This means:

1. You must define it somewhere. That is, put `int Environment::self;` into exactly one .cpp file. This fill fix your "Unresolver reference" linker error.
2. Being `static` means there's just one instance of `self` for the entire class.  Therefore, accessing it through `this->self` is not necessary, and is actually confusing. It seems to imply each instance of class `Environment` has its own copy, but that is in fact not true.

If you want each instance of `Enviornment` to have its own value of `self`, simply drop the `static` keyword from `self`'s declaration.

Comment: Is'nt it set by the line: bla=Environment::CTE;

Comment: @Anna `static` members declared in a class are only *declared* there, not *defined.* You still need to define (allocate space) for the variable somewhere (in a .cpp file). C++ isn't Python, variables don't "spring into being" by assigning into a name.